# org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn/rbESB/!svn/vcc/default) Failed to check out

Tags: jenkins, svn

Jenkins job is unable to checkout code .PFB error.

java.io.IOException: Failed to check out http://hostname:port/svn/rbESB/tags/dev/System/s-application/s-application-635

> Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002:
>   Processing REPORT request response failed: Premature end of file.
>   (/svn/rbESB/!svn/vcc/default)  svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on
>   '/svn/rbESB/!svn/vcc/default'

Comment: It got resolved . I performed below step.

Comment: Performed below changes in Jenkins file at /etc/sysconfig/Jenkins location.

Added -Dhudson.spool-svn=true in JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS argument.

Comment: JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS = "-Dhudson.spool-svn=true "  
Update at location  /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved . I performed below step. – Nirbhay Singh 16 hours ago
1
Performed below changes in Jenkins file at /etc/sysconfig/Jenkins location. Added -Dhudson.spool-svn=true in JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS argument. – Nirbhay Singh 16 hours ago
1
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS = "-Dhudson.spool-svn=true " Update at location /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file –